# How to convert string to 2D Array?

Tags: python, numpy

How to convert string list to 2d array

The string is

```
   ['43.417', '42.953', '43.417', '43.290', '43.105', '43.000', '43.105', '43.290', '42.426', '42.953',   
        '42.837', '42.720']

-> [43.417, 42.953],
   [42.417, 43.105],
   [43.105, 43.000],
,,,,
   [42.837, 42.720]
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where did the 42.417 come from? Where did the 43.290 go?

Comment: Is that a string or a list of strings?

Comment: Thanks, it is some coordinates of some shape.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use range and slice (no need to import any module):

```
>>> list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> [list_[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(list_), 2)]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group every 2 elements into a list and collect them all into a big list?

If the number of elements in the list is even:

```
newList = [oldList[k * 2 : (k + 1) * 2] for k in range(len(oldList) // 2)]
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

If the number of elements is odd and you want to include a list of 1 element at the end:

```
import math

newList = [oldList[k * 2 : (k + 1) * 2] for k in range(math.ceil(len(oldList) / 2))]
```

```
[1, 2, 3] -> [[1, 2], [3]]
```

If you don't want to include that 1-element list, then use the first case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of strings, we can copy-n-paste, and make an array:

```
In [149]: alist = ['43.417', '42.953', '43.417', '43.290', '43.105', '43.000', '43.105', '43.290', '4
     ...: 2.426', '42.953','42.837', '42.720']                                                       
In [150]: len(alist)                                                                                 
Out[150]: 12
In [151]: np.array(alist, dtype=float)                                                               
Out[151]: 
array([43.417, 42.953, 43.417, 43.29 , 43.105, 43.   , 43.105, 43.29 ,
       42.426, 42.953, 42.837, 42.72 ])
```

By specifying the dtype, `array` converts the strings to numbers.  If one or more is  not valid, it will produce an error.

Once we have the array, it is easy to reshape:

```
In [152]: np.array(alist, dtype=float).reshape(6,2)                                                  
Out[152]: 
array([[43.417, 42.953],
       [43.417, 43.29 ],
       [43.105, 43.   ],
       [43.105, 43.29 ],
       [42.426, 42.953],
       [42.837, 42.72 ]])
```